# SQL SELECT multiple columns into one

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, select

I have this query in SQL Server 2008:

```
SELECT Id, Year, Manufacturer, Model  
FROM Table
```

and I need something like this...

```
SELECT Id, (Year + [space] + Manufacturer + [space] + Model) AS MyColumn 
FROM Table
```

How can I get this result?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think all integer or numeric data types you need convert to String data type. When you can create your new column.

Query:

```
SELECT Id, (Cast([Year] as varchar(4)) + ' ' + Manufacturer + ' ' + Model) AS MyColumn 
FROM   Tablename
```

Answer (score 8):

just use `' '`

```
SELECT Id, ([Year] + ' ' + Manufacturer + ' ' + Model) AS MyColumn 
FROM   Tablename
```